# Error: The prefix “xsd” for element “xsd:schema” is not bound

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am getting a error that says

> The prefix "xsd" for element "xsd:element" is not bound.

My XSD file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--XSD schema for file companylist.xml-->

<CompanyList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="companies.xsd"> 
    <xsd:element name="CompanyList">
      <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Company"
                 maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CompanyID"
                    type="xsd:integer"/>
            <xsd:element name="contactname"
                    type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Is your question answered?  If so, please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) the answer that solved your problem or helped the most.  If not, please follow-up with a comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error,

> The prefix “xsd” for element “xsd:schema” is not bound

define the `xsd` namespace prefix as follows on the root `schema` element of the XSD:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Note also that the first tag of your XSD appears to be from an XML document instance.

Here is the entire XSD with the above problems resolved:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="CompanyList">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Company" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="CompanyID" type="xsd:integer"/>
              <xsd:element name="contactname" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```